# Не могу разобраться с LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq2sql, relation

Добрый день, друзья!
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с LINQ to SQL имеется БД с 2мя таблицами:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [LName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [MName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Persons] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phones](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Phones] PRIMARY KEY,
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY([PId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Persons] ([Id])
)
```

2 модели:

```
[Table(Name = "Persons")]

class Person
{
    private EntitySet<Phone> _Phone;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "FName", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "LName",CanBeNull = false)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "MName", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Association(Storage = "_Phone")]
    public EntitySet<Phone> Phone
    {
        set
        {
            _Phone = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _Phone;
        }
    }
}


 [Table(Name = "Phones")]
class Phone
{
    private EntityRef<Person> _Person;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "PId")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "Phone", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Association(Storage = "_Person")]
    public Person Person
    {
        set
        {
            _Person.Entity = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _Person.Entity;
        }
    }
}
```

и DataContext:

```
class PhonebookContext : DataContext
{
    public Table<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public Table<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    public PhonebookContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString) { }
}
```

Файл Program.cs

```
 class Program
{
    public static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PhonebookContext"].ConnectionString;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PhonebookContext db = new PhonebookContext(connectionString);
        /*var result = from persons in db.GetTable<Person>()
                     join phones in db.GetTable<Phone>() on persons.Id equals phones.PersonId
                     select new
                     {
                         FirstName = persons.FirstName,
                         LastName = persons.LastName,
                         MiddleName = persons.MiddleName,
                         PhoneNumber = phones.PhoneNumber
                     };*/
        var result = from person in db.Persons select person;

        foreach (Person person in result)
        {
            Console.Write(person.FirstName + ":\t");
            foreach (Phone phone in person.Phone)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(phone.PhoneNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

при запуске выдает ошибку `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll`
На строке где идет выборка в переменную `result`
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно делать.

Answer (score 1):

Все разобрался неправильно внес данные в Context, там не автосвойства

```
public Table<Person> Persons { get; set; }
public Table<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
```

заменить на

```
public Table<Person> Persons;
public Table<Phone> Phones;
```